# How to detect language of a dataframe object?

Tags: python, typeerror, language-detection

I want to create a new column in my dataframe review giving the language of the column text which is of type object.

I try to convert to string and then use the detect function from langdetect but, there still a type error when I run the code.

I do not understand the problem lol

My code :

```
from langdetect import detect


review['langue'] = detect((review['text']).astype(str))
```

Actual result :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)


TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: what's review? Is it dataframe? Can you paste some sample rows? What would be the output of detect?

Comment: Also, please post full traceback message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question you needs

```
from langdetect import detect
review['langue'] = review['text'].apply(detect)
```

`detect` function expect `str` as argument, not `pd.Series`. Instead, you should apply `detect` function to each element of `review['text']` `pd.Series`.

Comment: I tried your solution on DF column of 800,000 rows and it is very slow. DO you know any way I can make it faster? Thanks.

Comment: Use Pandararrel to speed the processing up:

from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=False)

review['langue'] = review['text'].parallel_apply(detect)

Comment: It is better to use `from langdetect import detect_langs` if you want to detect language of a text.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the answer provided by [kvorobieb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3899471/kvorobiev), you can make a function so that it works even when the detect does not find any alphabets in the given text:

```
from langdetect import detect
def detect_my(text):
   try:
       return detect(text)
   except:
       return 'unknown'

review['langue'] = review['text'].apply(detect_my)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for detecting the language for each row

```
for index, row in df['text'].iteritems():
    lang = detect(row) #detecting each row
    df.loc[index, 'language'] = lang
```